# correct way to provide Spring configuration files in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

In my sample SPring project I'm using the following web.xml,
I think that it fails to properly use
root-context.xml
servlet-context.xml
security-context.xml

How should I change it in order to provide these three configuration files
correctly ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/app-security-context.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical the filter-mapping is located after the servlet mapping ([Adjusting web.xml listeners, filters and servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452804/adjusting-web-xml-listeners-filters-and-servlets))

One other thing looks strange: you wrote that you have a:

- root-context.xml
- servlet-context.xml
- security-context.xml

Of course the name "root-context.xml" is not standardized, but I expect that his is the spring configuration file that contains the services, DAO, db connection but not the web-controller stuff. If it is so, then you should load your `root-context.xml` with the "inner-application context" created by `ContextLoaderListener` and configured by context-param `contextConfigLocation`.  The `security-context.xml` MUST also been loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`, so if there is no import for `security-context.xml` in `root-context.xml` then you must configure them both in `contextConfigLocation`

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/root-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/app-security-context.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

---

Maybe you should have a look at this question: [ContextLoaderListener or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not) - the question an the accepted answer explain a bit of how the two contexts work.

Comment: thanks,also one thing I've alway wondered , if the name roo-context is not standardized, how  does spring know that that file is the root context and that all the beans defined in it are also inherited by child contexts such  as security and servlet ?

Comment: GionJh: roo or root context?

Comment: According to ContextLoader javaDoc: the default name would be : `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`:   > "If not explicitly specified, the context implementation is supposed to use a default location (with XmlWebApplicationContext: "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")"

Comment: I don't quite understand...in the code above you are providing two file to the context configuration, yet one os interpreted as the root-context the other as the security context, how does spring do that ?

Comment: Spring will "merge" the configuration of both files togerher.

Comment: but security-context isn't a child configuration context of root context ? just like servlet-context is ? or am I getting something wrong here ?

Comment: Just imagine that Spring parse both files together. No Child context, just one context, that's description is split into two files.

Comment: ia servlet context a child context of root context ?

Comment: Yes: the context created by the `DispatcherServlet` become a child context of the one that is created by the `ContextLoaderListener`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>

        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-security.xml,
            classpath:spring-mybatis.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <!-- 此处可以可以配置成*.do，对应struts的后缀习惯 -->
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 编码过滤器 -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Spring监听器 -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- 防止Spring内存溢出监听器 -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```